# Plugins for APEX 3.2

Tags: plugins, oracle-apex

Are there any plugins for Application Express 3.2?  Every plugin I can find requires APEX 4.0 at a minumum.

I was specifically interested in a plugin that would allow multiple file uploads such as [this one](http://www.apex-plugin.com/oracle-apex-plugins/item-plugin/multiple-file-upload_95.html)

Per company policy, I am not able to upgrade to a higher version of APEX.

Comment: Company policies, don't you just love them? ;-)  I bet they insist on IE6 too (mine does!)

Comment: I am up to IE7 now.  I think we are getting IE9 late next year.  Firefox, Chrome, etc are not allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The APEX plug-in architecture was introduced in version 4.0.  Prior to that, plug-ins were not  available in APEX.